# In App Purchase: want to add non consumable items dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I know this question is asked before but didn't get my answer there.
Project function: - In my project server team will upload In App Product (IAP) dynamically on daily basis in CMS. There will be only one product available for free for all users and other products are need to buy. All products are Non-Consumable. My IAP can be more than 10k. Price for all IAP is same $0.99.

**Question: -**

1] How to add these IAP dynamically on iTunesconnect?

2] Is there any Apple api to add IAP on iTuneConnect?

3] Is there any other option than adding IAP manually?

4] Can I create IAP with the wide character?

5] Is there any need for restore button, because I am keeping all records in my server database?